# LP to compute all cuts between 2 vertices of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

Given an undirected graph $G$ (for example a symmetric adjacency matrix) without weights, I want to compute all cuts of two chosen vertices in the graph.

Actually there is an R-function st_cuts of package 'igraph' that does this, but I (and more people) get errors with this function while it should compute the cuts.

Therefore I want to make an own function (in R) that computes for a given pair of vertices $(s,t)$, all the $s-t$ cuts between vertices $s$ and $t$. Preferably with each cut expressed in edges.
I know that the number of cuts between $s$ and $t$ may be far larger then the number of edges and vertices, but the graphs I consider are not that big (maximal 35 vertices and 40 edges).

There are algorithms that compute the min s-t cut, but I want all s-t cuts.

Does anyone know an LP which solves this (or another way to program it)?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: An adjacency matrix is usually not considered directed.

Comment: @Jorden there may be many many cuts between $s$ and $t$ though. The number of cuts between two vertices $s$ and $t$ in a graph $G$ may infact be far far larger than the number of vertices in $G$ (depends on $G$, $s$, and $t$). I am pretty sure it in fact usually is.

Comment: @coffeemath You are right, My input graph is undirected, but most of the time you have to make it directed to compute cuts. Therefore the adjacency matrix will be symmetric.

Comment: @Mike You are also right, I edited this in the post. The graphs I consider are not that big. But your argument confirms that we need a LP to obtain all cuts of vertices $s$ and $t$.